# Using detox to look at UI in different orientations (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, detox

So I am using [detox](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DeviceObjectAPI.md#devicetakescreenshotname) to take screenshots of my app. I'm using a connected Android device. The device.takeScreenshot function works. Now what is the best way to see what my app looks like on different orientations? Is the only way to just change the tablet orientation and run the test again? Or is there a smarter way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here, but in order to change orientation you can use [`device.setOrientation()`](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DeviceObjectAPI.md#devicesetorientationorientation).

> Is the only way to just change the tablet orientation and run the test again?

To me, this sounds like two separate use cases (portrait vs. vertical). Would be easier to maintain.

Lastly, as far as screenshot testing is concerned, you might find the practices described in Detox's [screenshots guide](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Screenshots.md) useful:

> ...
>
> the concept is mainly useful for verifying the proper visual structure and layout of elements appearing on the device's screen, in the form of a snapshot-test. Namely, by following these conceptual steps:
>
> 1. Taking a screenshot, once, and manually verifying it, visually.
> 2. Storing it as an e2e-test asset (i.e. the snapshot).
> 3. Using it as the point-of-reference for comparison against screenshots taken in consequent tests, from that point on.
>
> ```js
> const fs = require('fs');
>
> describe('Members area', () => {
>  const snapshottedImagePath = './e2e/assets/snapshotted-image.png';
>
>  it('should greet the member with an announcement', async () => {
>    const imagePath = (take screenshot from the device); // Discussed >below
>    expectBitmapsToBeEqual(imagePath, snapshottedImagePath);  
>  });  
> });
>
> function expectBitmapsToBeEqual(imagePath, expectedImagePath) {
>  const bitmapBuffer = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);
>  const expectedBitmapBuffer = fs.readFileSync(expectedImagePath);
>  if (!bitmapBuffer.equals(expectedBitmapBuffer)) {
>    throw new Error(`Expected image at ${imagePath} to be equal to image >at ${expectedImagePath}, but it was different!`);
>  }
> }
> ```
>
> Important: The recommended, more practical way of doing this, is by utilizing more advanced 3rd-party image snapshotting & comparison tools such as applitools.

Comment: So the guide for device.setOrientation(orientation) says "Currently only available in the iOS Simulator.". https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DeviceObjectAPI.md#devicesetorientationorientation

Is the documentation just out of date? I want it to work on an Android device (physical).

Comment: Sorry about that. It should work on Android as well!